# How stop elements from moving

Tags: html, css

just a quick question. I have recently dicovered the use for percentages and positioning in css. However I'm having a little trouble with moving elements.

I have two Images one on the left side of the screen and one on the right. both images are set to relevent positioning. The issue im having is getting the image on the right to stay put rather than moving to stay in frame of the window. How would I achieve this using percentages?

**Css**

```
.left {
position:relative;
left:0%;
z-index:250;
}

.right {
position:relative;
right:100%;
z-index:250;
}
```

**ADDED ON REQUEST**

```
/* -- page layout */
#wrapper {
position:relative;
width:auto;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 0;
}
#wrapper #head{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:50px;
z-index:200;
margin:0;
margin:0;
}
```

**Note**

These images are placed within a a div, that spans 100% of the screen. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show your HTML and CSS that affects the parent elements.

Comment: There we are, thats my content wrap and the header that the images are placed within.

Comment: What is *"relevant"* positioning. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* -- page layout */
#wrapper {
position:relative;
width:auto;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 0;

min-width: 1280px;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

This has fixed it for me! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, try

```
.right {
  position:relative;
  left: 80%;
  z-index:250;
}
```

I recommend using `float` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/beautifulcoder/HCjvK/

Comment: Close, I have switched to float now. Currently have the image floating to the right however it still follows the right side of the browser when I resize. eventiually crushing up against the image on the left. I would rather have all the content sit firmly im place. (but still allow it to scroll downwards with the page.

Comment: Sounds like media queries might be what you need when you resize

Comment: No I have settings set for different devices, I needed to stop elements from moving when adjusting the browser window on a desktop.